# Django admin dashboard, is there a way to lowercase model name?

Tags: django, admin, django-grappelli

I'm looking for a way to lowercase the first letter of a model in my django admin site.

i.e.:
model verbose name is "agent-1.0.0" is shown as "Agent-1.0.0" on the dashboard,

simple but IDK

grappelli trick will also work for me.

django - 1.7.1

also - need this only for one app models group - not all of my dashboard should be lowercase...
so, overriding the index.html is not so efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capitalization is [hard-coded in the template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html#L42), same for the [templates in Grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/blob/master/grappelli/templates/admin/change_list.html#L151).

You can use catavaran's suggestion, but this will transform every model name. Overriding the template is a huge pain in the ass to maintain for something this small.

The only workable solution I can think of is to bypass the `capfirst` filter with a space:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = " agent-1.0.0"
```

As `capfirst` only forcibly capitalizes the first character, nothing will happen if the first character is not a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Model name passed to template as `capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)` so you have to lowercase it in the `admin/index.html` tempate or via CSS.  Imho CSS option is simpler:

```
div.module tr[class^=model-] th {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

If you want lowercase only some models (for example `User`) then change CSS selector to this:

```
div.module tr.model-user th {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but i meant for some models only - i'll edit my Q -sorry

Answer (score 0):

With Grapelli you could create a custom Dashboard by running:

```
 python manage.py customdashboard
```

and setting GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD on your settings to your custom class.

You can make this custom class extend from the Dashboard class that grappelli offers and override it to your needs. Look especially at the [ModelList](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_api.html#the-modellist-class) class, where you can specify the title you want for the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS-way for those who don't want to override Django admin classes. Override and extend `templates/admin/base_site.html` template as follows:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <style>
        h1.model-title {text-transform: lowercase;}
        h1.model-title:first-letter {text-transform: uppercase;}
    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content_title %}
    {% if title %}<h1 class="model-title">{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will make **only** first letter of each `content_title`  uppercase.

You can use the same way to lowercase model name in admin tables as well as sidebar. However, I'd like to point that by tacit agreement model's `verbose_name` as well as `verbose_name_plural` shouldn't be capitalized. This will save you a lot of overrides in your project, like I provided above to normalize `change_list` header.